# Android String Builder reading per line

Tags: android, string, stringbuilder

I need to read a line from a string builder.
The problem is when I execute .toString()... It will become a single string which I don't know how to get a line from it.
I've read a question similar to mine, and get this answer:

---

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("line 1");
sb.append("\\n");
sb.append("line 2");

String[] lines = sb.toString().split("\\n");
for(String s: lines){
    System.out.println("Content = " + s);
    System.out.println("Length = " + s.length());
}
```

The problem is, what if the "line 1" or "line 2" is actually a PASSWORD, which could contain any possible combination of string, including "\\n" inside?
Please help.

Comment: What do you want to solve by concatenating strings in stringbuilder and then splitting em? 
Anyway there's a split() function with 2 arguments, which allows you to split string into fixed number of strings. This will protect you from new lines in second string.

Comment: Are you required to use StringBuilder?  E.g., the problem that you pose would be much easier if you used ArrayList<String>.

Comment: actually it's not that I'm concatenating strings then splitting them again with no reason... I'm actually working for an encryption program which requires me reading from file... when it writes the encrypted message to file, it has to be concatenated... when I read back, I have to find a way to split them... and this is my main problem...

Comment: @user2266464, i think you are doing something wrong. If you want to store strings with newlines in file, you can either encode new line in them (with something like urlencode) or have binary file with saving strings as byte arrays in them with preceeding array length, so you can always read array length, than entire array, and then create new string from this byte array while reading file.

Comment: @infthi: it seems you get it wrong... like I said, I store an encrypted string in file... means what's inside the file is some random characters... so I can't say if there is a newline in file... but when I read the encrypted string then decrypt it, I have to split it (the decrypted string)... and I can't figure out how...

Comment: @user2266464, the simple solution is: use objectoutputstream to generate file (call writeUTF() so store encoded string variables), and read the file with objectinputstream (readutf() will read the encoded string you wrote with objectoutputstream).

Comment: @infthi: well, the problem is not the reading... actually when I read the file, things are working perfectly, even after I decrypt the string back... the problem is after the decryption... how do I read newline from the concatenated string, considering the possibility that there is a line (a password for example) which contains a newline character inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use a "reader" like FileReader, Reader, Scanner instead a "builder/writer".

Take a look [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42) , some tutorials and good exemple for reading and writing files.